# /dev/mem: mmap: Operation not permitted: Using dmidecode

Tags: 12.04, server, ssh, firmware

I am trying to get my BIOS firmware version, and memory info using dmidecode. I am connected to the server through ssh as a root user. We recently just started moving our servers from Debian 6.0, to Ubuntu 12.4 LTS. Is there another way to get the BIOS info, or someway to get dmidecode to work? Even when I run dmidecode alone, with no options, I still get the same message.

```
root@'machine':~# dmidecode | grep -A3 -i 'bios information'
# dmidecode 2.9
SMBIOS 2.6 present.
61 structures occupying 3910 bytes.
Table at 0x00099000.

/dev/mem: mmap: Operation not permitted
```

Also rebooting the servers is not really an option to get the BIOS info

Comment: It is probably secure boot (setting in the BIOS)