# /dev/mem and even /dev/port can't open even as root!

Tags: permissions, kubuntu, 22.04

I made a program that tries to do mmaping on /dev/mem and it fails with:

> Failed to open /dev/mem: Operation not permitted

And I tried using od as a test for my code being bad too:

> od: /dev/mem: Operation not permitted

> od: /dev/port: Operation not permitted

I am also running Kubuntu 22.04 LTS

To clarify, I never mmaped /dev/port.

How do I make these files open-able?

Comment: Writing directly to hardware is discouraged in Linux. Try another approach. `man -k sound`

Comment: See: [/dev/mem: mmap: Operation not permitted: Using dmidecode](https://askubuntu.com/q/508754/1391094)

Comment: @Rinzwind I never mmaped /dev/port, only /dev/mem I tried to open /dev/port though

Comment: @Rinzwind It still dosen't explain the od failing (outputting 0 characters) on /dev/mem and /dev/port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it was secure boot in the BIOS; run `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` then disable secure boot in the BIOS setup.

Answer (score 1):

It is a kernel parameter named `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM`. By default, since kernel 2.6.26, it is disabled and as such does not allow access to it.

Find out what you have it set to:

```
$ ll /proc/ | grep conf
$ ll /boot/ | grep conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   261604 Apr 19 14:01 config-5.15.0-1033-gcp
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   234065 Apr 10  2020 config-5.4.0-1009-gcp
$ cd /boot/
$ more config-5.15.0-1033-gcp | grep CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM
CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM=y
```

See `man 4 mem` on command line. Excerpt:

> Since Linux  2.6.26,  and  depending  on  the  architecture,  the  `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM`  kernel  configuration  option limits the areas which
> can be accessed through this file.  For example: on x86, RAM access  is not allowed but accessing memory-mapped PCI regions is.
>
> It is typically created by:
>
> ```
> mknod -m 660 /dev/mem c 1 1
> chown root:kmem /dev/mem
> ```

So you need to disable `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` and that will require recompiling the kernel. 2 links about it (but it is a little bit beyond "Ubuntu"):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129785/how-to-disable-config-strict-devmem-through-make-menuconfig-or-make-nconfig
- https://superuser.com/questions/1404426/how-to-customize-a-linux-kernel-modify-config-strict-devmem

Comment: Memory-mapped PCI devices should still work it explicitly says, and that's what I'm doing, opening should still be allowed as root.